# Creando Fourfold Plots pero la función ffold.local () crea un error

Tags: r

Dice que el paquete que se debe de usar para crear Fourfold Plot es `graphics` también estoy usando el paquete `vcd` `vcdExtra` y tengo esta base de datos

```
                 |                       Highest degree obtained                             |
Welfare spending | LT high school | High school | Junior college | Bachelor | Graduate | Total 
Too little              45              116            19            48          23       251 
About right             40              167            33            68          41       349 
Too much                47              185            34            63          26       355 
Total                   132             468            86            179         90       955
```

ahora con este código la convierto a matrix

```
freq <- c(45,116,19,48,23,40,167,33,68,41,47,185,34,63,26)
natfare <- matrix(freq, byrow=TRUE,ncol=5) 
dimnames(natfare) <- list(WELFARE=c("too little","about right", "too much"), DEGREE=c("LT HS","HS", "JColg","BA", "Grad"))
```

y ahora con este comando

```
ffold.local (natfare)
```

debería de salir

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Cuando ejecuto sale este error

```
ffold.local (natfare)
Error in ffold.local(natfare) : 
  no se pudo encontrar la función "ffold.local"
```

Comment: La función `ffold.local()` no existe, ese básicamente es el error. ¿De que paquete es la misma? ¿lo has cargado antes?

Comment: en el ejemplo del capitulo del libro dice que los packages que se utilizan son:  graphics , vcd, cvd, vcdExtra

Comment: Me parece que lo que estás leyendo puede que sea relativamente "antiguo", el paquete `cvd` en minúsculas no existe en CRAN, y en ninguno de los otros paquetes existe la función `ffold.local()`, ¿No será una función escrita en el libro la que te está faltando?